# Finding nested tag values of XML file using Shell Script

Tags: xml, shell

I have an XML file of the format:

```
<classes>

 <subjects>
    <subject>
        <name>Operating System</name>
        <credit>3</credit>
        <type>Theory + Lab</type>
        <faculty>Prof. XYZ</faculty> 
    </subject>

    <subject>
        <name>Web Development</name>
        <credit>3</credit>
        <type>Theory + Lab</type>
        <faculty>Prof. ABC</faculty> 
    </subject>
 </subjects>

</classes>
```

I need to find the value of 'name' tag which is nested inside the /subject/subjects tag.
How can I get the values of 'name' tag?

Answer (score 0):

Shell interpreters (like `sh` or `bash`) are not well suited to parsing `xml` data.  You would be better off to use a tool like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` to select elements from an `xml` file and pass them back to the shell for further processing.

Comment: Requirement is to use Shell instead of xmlstarlet.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'Shell'?